# Using .apply() in Sframes to manipulate multiple columns of each row

Tags: python, sframe

I have an SFrame with the columns Date1 and Date2.

I am trying to use `.apply()` to find the datediff between Date1 and Date2, but I can't figure out how to use the other argument.

Ideally something like

```
frame['new_col'] = frame['Date1'].apply(lambda x: datediff(x,frame('Date2')))
```

Comment: so you looking to have difference in days ?

Comment: Yes. But trying to avoid iterating and instead using the .apply() function.

Comment: `frame['Date1'] - frame['Date2']` doesn't work?

Comment: no... it gives a result which I am not sure what the units are... like 9/6/2016 - 5/2/2016 gives a number in the tens of thousands which is not months or days...

Comment: It's just the number of seconds between the two dates. You can simply use the `apply` method to convert that into days: `(frame['Date2'] - frame['Date1']).apply(lambda x: round(x/(60*60*24)))`.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly take the difference between the dates in column `Date2` and those in `Date1` by just subtracting `frame['Date1']` from `frame['Date2']`. That, for some reason, returns the number of seconds between the two dates (only tested with python's `datetime` objects), which you can convert into *number of days* with simple arithmetics:

```
from sframe import SFrame
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

mydict = {'Date1':[datetime.now(), datetime.now()+timedelta(2)], 
          'Date2':[datetime.now()+timedelta(10), datetime.now()+timedelta(17)]}
frame = SFrame(mydict)
frame['new_col'] = (frame['Date2'] - frame['Date1']).apply(lambda x: x//(60*60*24))
```

Output:

```
+----------------------------+----------------------------+---------+
|           Date1            |           Date2            | new_col |
+----------------------------+----------------------------+---------+
| 2016-10-02 21:12:14.712556 | 2016-10-12 21:12:14.712574 |   10.0  |
| 2016-10-04 21:12:14.712567 | 2016-10-19 21:12:14.712576 |   15.0  |
+----------------------------+----------------------------+---------+
```